# Set card view's background using Remote View

Tags: java, android, widget, remoteview

I use the following codes to set background of view such as `TextView`, `LinearLayout`, and it works perfectly.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setInt(R.id.textview, "setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor(widgetTextColor.toString()));
```

But I try to set the background of `CardView`, it didn't works. I have tried

```
views.setInt(R.id.cardview, "setCardBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor(widgetTextColor.toString()));
```

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the developer documentation in this link, u cannot use **cardview** for App widgets

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

and a discussion about this already been over here [What views can i use in an appWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037737/what-views-can-i-use-in-an-appwidget)